# In my code username in the form1 should be displayed in the textbox of form2 on buttonclick

Tags: vb.net, forms, textbox, return

1. Private Sub Command1_Click()
2. usnm = Text1.Text
3. pass = Text2.Text
4. Shell "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\New folder\form2.exe", vbNormalNoFocus
5. End Sub

Comment: assuming this is code from form1. nothing in this sets a textbox text on form2. why do you think it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a **module** in the current project called **Memory.vb**
In Memory.vb type

```
Public CurrentUser as string = "notLoggedIn"
Public CurrentPassword as string = "notLoggedIn"
```

Then create another **form** in your current project called **Form2**
Add your textbox to Form2 and call it UsernameTextbox
Then double click on the background of form2 and it should give you a new sub. In between the Private Sub and the End Sub, type:

```
UsernameTextbox.Text = CurrentUser
```

Now we have to go back to Command1_Click and put this in:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    CurrentUser = Text1.Text
    CurrentPassword = Text2.Text
    Form2.show()
End Sub
```

That should do what you want it to...

Comment: Make sure it's in the Command1_Click() sub and that the 's' in show is capital letter unless your using a decent IDE like visual studio.

Comment: yes i have used the code as you have said but the problem is that when i run the application first form opens and when i click the button form2 doesn't get open it shows the syntax error if code of form1 and makes Form2.Show() red.